A series of problems with Raspberry Pi 5 NVME m.2 hat
My Specification:

NVME HAT: Suptronics X1002 Raspberry Pi 5 nvme M.2
Installed SSD disk: Samsung M.2 970 EVO Plus 1000 GB PCIe Gen 3.0 x4 V-NAND 3bit
Installed OS: Ubuntu Server

Problems I encountered:

After installing the module and connecting NVME, I found that the Internet connection was lost. If I disconnect the SSD, the connection returns and I can work via SSH.
I found information that I need to add the following to the cmdline.txt file located in /boot/firmware:
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 pcie_aspm=off

After rebooting, I can't find the SSD disk.
lsblk does not display the NVME SSD.
I checked this disk on another device - it is visible.
I took another 256GB NVME SSD disk and connected it via HAT to RP
5 - it is displayed via lsblk.


How much power does the drive need? I have seen some very power-hungry Samsung devices. And what power supply do you use?

@Dirk I use the original power supply 5V 25.5W. Samsung 970 EVO Plus 1TB consumes 3.3V and 2.7A

@jsotola after entering this line and rebooting, this SSD is not displayed. Any other one becomes visible - for example, I inserted a nvme m.2 ssd of 256GB (it consumes 3.3V and 1.3A). I ​​inserted a Samsung SSD of 1TB into other devices - it is also visible.

@jsotola edited!

"Internet connection is lost" you mean by cable or WIFI? Hat may be shielding that poor wifi antenna on Pi5, there may be some buck converter nearby that radiates noise and blocks wifi...

@dingo27mobile by cable.
